# How to implement autosuggestion for dynamically created text box

Tags: jquery, autosuggest

My code is given below. I got it from a website. but i think something is missing. please help me to finish my task. Thanks in advance

//HTML

```
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
    <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
    <div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"></div>
</div>
```

//JS

```
    var availableAttributes = [
          "account_address",
          "account_address_city",
          "account_address_country",
          "account_address_state",.
          "account_address_street1",
          "account_address_street2",
          "account_address_zip",
          "account_email",
          "account_login",
          "account_name",
          "account_number",
          "account_telephone"
        ];

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
        var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
        var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div><input id="' + x + '" type="text" name="mytext"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>');

 //add input box


 $( "input[id="+ x +"]" ).autocomplete({
                source: availableAttributes
            }); 
        }
    });

   });
```

Comment: Please give more details. Is there something wrong with this code? Why does it not work for you?

Comment: Please edit to make the last bit of code part of the code block...

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i think some links are missing. Can you please suggest suitable links?

Comment: @VarunCV offtopic to what you want but it might be worth looking at select2 library for nice prebuilt things like this

Answer (score 0):

The issue is very minute. Your json is wrong. It has a `.` in the json after `account_address_state`

Check the working demo [codepen](https://codepen.io/agamb/pen/OmoqpY) after fixing the json